# Copy 'False Positive' between projects created for different git branches of the same git repository

Tags: sonarqube

Please let me know, if there is a way to copy 'False Positive' between projects created for different git branches of the same git repository.

Example:

- Lets say i have a git repository abc.git
- Now lets say this git repository is having three branches master, develop & release
- I am passing -Dsonar.branch with sonar-scanner and it create three
  projects for each of these branches.
- Now if a developer mark an issue as 'False Positive' on master branch then is there a way where the same issues is marked 'False Positive' for other two branches develop & release.

Comment: I created a simple command line tool for this, please see [my answer at another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43279845/7333940).

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is meaty, full-featured support within SonarQube for branches. Sorry, but it's just not there yet. :-(